# MDX query level wise sum

Tags: ssas, mdx

My problem is related to MDX query. I will try to explain it in very simple example.
Lets assume there is a STATE with 2 city "City-A" and "City-B" with customer count is 3 & 4, amount is 700 and 900 respectively.

Now business logic is if any City has customer count more than 3 then show amount. so answer is City-B, Customer count - 4, amount - 900

but when i try same formula at STATE level i get
 STATE-1, Customer count - 7, amount - 1600

Is there any way where we can specify in MDX query that first apply business logic at city level and then sum it up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you want dynamic aggregations (ie, a parent total that reflects the filter applied at a lower level), you can use a sub-select.

Compare a query where we filter the set of customers in the selection:

```
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,
    Union(
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All Customers], 
        Filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],
               [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] > 6000)
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]

// Results
               Internet Order Quantity  Internet Sales Amount
All Customers                   60,398         $29,358,677.22
Australia                       13,345          $9,061,000.58
Canada                           7,620          $1,977,844.86
United Kingdom                   6,906          $3,391,712.21
United States                   21,344          $9,389,789.51
```

with a query where we sub-select the filtered set of customers, causing a re-aggregation, and then select the new totals:

```
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0,
    Union(
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[All Customers],
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country]
    ) ON 1
FROM (
    SELECT Filter([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country],
                  [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] > 6000) ON 0
    FROM [Adventure Works]
)

// Results
               Internet Order Quantity  Internet Sales Amount
All Customers                   49,215         $23,820,347.17
Australia                       13,345          $9,061,000.58
Canada                           7,620          $1,977,844.86
United Kingdom                   6,906          $3,391,712.21
United States                   21,344          $9,389,789.51
```